# How to reduce memory usage of a windows form application in C# VS 2010 Professional

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

I have an application with a simple gui, very few graphics but a lot of objects ie. labels text boxes and a few panels.
On some panels it runs LDAP queries, in others it queries processes running and checks NIC status.
When I go to the LDAP searcher panel, memory usage drops down to app 30mb, when I return to the main panel that only runs a timer, It jumps to about 300mb + then keeps accumulating, I run GC.Collect() as often as I can, on minimize after primary methods have been run and such still to no effect, ive used optimize code under build in project properties and ive stripped out all of the Using system.whatever.  I am a reasonably new programmer, its only been about 6 months since I started doing windows forms.  Any help would be nice.  My application is essentially a GUI that sits there with a timer running in the background, then does the aforementioned queries and some task skills.  Nothing too memory intensive.  Could the gui objects themselves be eating up my memory?

```
    public MainMethod()
    {
        try
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;


            // this.Opacity = .5;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000 * 10;

            pword();
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.Hide();
            this.Visible = false;
           // GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventWriter(ex);
        }

    }
    public void pword()
    {
        try
        {

            bool nCheck;
            string[] infoArray = new string[4];
            nCheck = checker.checkNetwork();
            int dayNum = 0;

            if (nCheck == true)
            {

                infoArray = checker.checkAD();   //this is similar code to CheckNetwork except it returns values from the user's AD account properties.
                label3.Text = infoArray[0];
                label2.Text = infoArray[2];
                label1.Text = infoArray[3];
                label21.Text = infoArray[0];
                label22.Text = infoArray[1];
                label23.Text = infoArray[2];
                label24.Text = infoArray[3];
                days = infoArray[3];
                dayNum = int.Parse(days);
                if (dayNum <= 15)
                {
                    timedIntervalChanger(2);
                    aTimer.Start();
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                timedIntervalChanger(1);
                aTimer.Start();
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventWriter(ex);
        }
```

}
public bool checkNetwork()
        {
            bool connected;
            try
            {

```
            String objectName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;


            if (objectName.Contains("administrator"))
            {
                connected = false;
                return connected;
            }

            else
            {





                // Sets domain
                string LdapDomain = "mydomain.com"
                //Sets properties for directory Entry and Searcher
                string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + LdapDomain;
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
                DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);


                mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(|(cn=" + objectName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + objectName + ")))";

                //instantiates result object from the search

                SearchResult LDAPresult = mySearcher.FindOne();

                entry = LDAPresult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                connected = true;

            }
            return connected;
        }
        catch
        {
            connected = false;
            return connected;
        }
    }
    public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000 * 9, "Test", "test text", ToolTipIcon.Warning);


         pword();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventWriter(ex);
        }


    }
```

It's when I show the form that the memory usage jumps tremendously.  Each method is independant and I left out some of the object instantiation code.

Comment: What problems are you observing?

Comment: As @mjmarsh said, we could help you some more if you can show us some of your source code. (But, his suggestions are good.)

Comment: Just overall way too much memory being used, its not really affecting the machine but I would like a small application to not use 300mb of memory.

Comment: You're aware that the usual advice is to avoid GC.Collect because it decreases performance, right? It forces objects into higher generations and causes each collection to take longer. Use it if you really know what you're doing, but don't just pepper it through your code.

Comment: what allocations deos the timer make? stuff that happens in a loop (or timer) is were you should look, and like everone here said, post some code please? also how are you measuring the memory consumption ?. can you give numbers from the Bytes in all heaps counter and the private bytes counter? (so we know what kind of memory to look for).

Comment: after the timer runs it calls a ballon tip on a notification Icon.  There is a lot of code to this program, any particular peices you want me to post?  I dont know how to measure memory consumption im going off of what is in task manager.  I believe I am using GC collect incorrectly then.

Answer (score 3):

We really need more info here.  But a few suggestions:

1. Use the `using` keyword or call `Dispose()` on all disposable objects when you are done with them
2. Make sure you unregister event handlers when you are done listening for events

I am not sure what LDAP library you are using but in System.DirectoryServices many of the classes (like `DirectoryEntry`) implement `IDisposable` and can 'leak' if they are not disposed of

Comment: I am using System.DirectoryServices and Directory entry, directorysearcher, essentially im querying LDAP for a specific user account and returning various user object properties.  The memory usage begins before I instantiate those objects.

Comment: I will go through and call a dispose on any objects not being used, I had a feeling that GC.Collect didnt pick them up.

Comment: What other info are you looking for I will supply with whatever is needed.

Comment: I have used a try catch finally block, and disposed of the objects in the finally block and my memory usage has not spiked over 19mb.

Comment: @theJerm - you have to do two things.  Keep a variable that holds your delegate reference and then use the "-=" notation on the event. e.g.: http://pastebin.com/7UpiNKjM

Answer (score 0):

Use the .NET Memory Allocation option of the Performance Wizard found in the Analyze menu to create a Performance Session which will help you figure out what changes you need to make in your code to reduce memory usage.